# Is it possible to use Vue Buefy autocomplete as select with search?

Tags: vue.js, select, search, buefy

I would like to make select input which will be able to search items in data source. According [documentation to select](https://buefy.org/documentation/select) it seems it is not possible to do it via select component. I tried to use [autocomplete component](https://buefy.org/documentation/autocomplete) instead of it, but it does not work.
The code with both examples is here. non of them works as expected (select with search with key as v-model value)

```
<b-autocomplete
    v-model="company.country"
    :data="selectCountries"
    :field="value"
    :keep-first="keepFirst"
    placeholder="Select country"
    :open-on-focus="openOnFocus"
<b-field label="Find a name">
    @select="option => (selected = option)"
    :clearable="clearable"
>
</b-autocomplete>
    </b-field>
    <b-select v-model="company.location" expanded>
        <option v-for="option in selectCountries"
            :value="option.key"
            :key="option.key">
            {{ option.value }}
        </option>
    </b-select>
</field>
...
data() {
    return {
        selectCountries: [
            {"value": "slovakia", "key": "SK"}, {"value": "England", "key": "EN"}
        ],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for the autocomplete to work, you need to filter the list yourself and pass the results back to the component. To do this, we created a computed property like this:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <b-autocomplete v-model="country" :data="filteredCountries" field="name" :keep-first="true" placeholder="Select Country" :open-on-focus="true"></b-autocomplete>
  </section>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
export default {
  data: () => ({
    country: '',
    countries: [
      {
        name: 'Slovakia',
        key: 'SK'
      },
      {
        name: 'England',
        key: 'EN'
      },
      {
        name: 'United States of America',
        key: 'USA'
      }
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    filteredCountries () {
      if (this.country !== null) {
        return this.countries.filter((option) => {
          return option.name.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(this.country.toLowerCase()) >= 0
        })
      } else {
        return this.countries
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```